# Crear arboles binarios en PHP

Tags: php

Alguien sabe como hacer un arbol binario en php, que permitar insertar y eliminar nodos, soy nuevo en esto de la programacion, si pudiera alguien mostrarme un ejemplo lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentaré darte un ejemplo sencillo:

```
public class Node {

    private $leftNode;
    private $rightNode;

    public function setLeftNode($node){
       $this->leftNode = $node;
    }
    public function setRightNode($node){
       $this->rightNode = $node;
    }
    public function getLeftNode(){
       return $this->leftNode;
    }
    public function getRightNode(){
       return $this->rightNode;
    }
    public function isLeaf(){
        return $this->leftNode === null && $this->rightNode === null;
    }
}
```

A partir de esta estructura ya puedes empezar a jugar agregando nodos y quitando, por ejemplo:

```
$nodo = new Nodo();
$nodo->setRightNode(new Node());
```

Haz creado un nodo que tiene un hijo derecho, y así puedes ir armando lo que necesites. Para eliminar basta con llamar al set enviándole null como parámetro.

Tiene solo hijo derecho e izquierdo porque es un arbol binario, de otra forma sería una colección de hijos.

Saludos

Comment: genial, muchas gracias